# Architecting persistence in React with Redux and Persistors

Tags: reactjs, redux, persist

I am noticing that certain things are not being saved due to the fact that I am saving them before rehydration happens.

```
var engagement = store.getState().analytics.engagement;
store.dispatch(engagementSave(engagement + 1));

...
<PersistGate loading={<Loading />} persistor={persistor}>
...
```

apparently rehydrates after UI render - so should I do most of my "startup" initialization in a dummy component/login page?

How are store updates typically done in React upon initialization?

Would I just execute them inside the persistor?

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently a callback that fires after the persistor rehydrates, you can use this to do things to your store immediately on initialization.

```
  let persistor = persistStore(store, {}, () => {
    console.log("state is persisted");
    const state = store.getState()
    console.log(state);
  })
```